# Postgresql function failed with “ERROR: could not open relation with OID " when create a temp table

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql 9.5.6 and using temp table in some functions, like : `create temp table xxx() on commit drop;`

when I execute the function, it occasionally ends up with error:

> ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 17221405 at character xx

It is strange that it is not always error;

The part of the pg_log content as follows:

```
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 17221405 at haracter 19
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST QUERY:  create temp table temp_powStaId(powStaId int) on commit drop
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST QUERY:  create temp table temp_powStaId(powStaId int) on commit drop
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_read_powsta_cache_by_userid(integer) line 26 at SQL statement
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST STATEMENT:  select * from fn_read_powsta_cache_by_userid($1) as result
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2017-05-16 08:00:03 CST STATEMENT:  SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM, c.relname AS TABLE_NAME,  CASE n.nspname ~ '^pg_' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema'  WHEN true THEN CASE  WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema' THEN CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TABLE'   WHEN 'v' THEN 'SYSTEM VIEW'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'SYSTEM INDEX'   ELSE NULL   END  WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_toast' THEN CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST TABLE'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST INDEX'   ELSE NULL   END  ELSE CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'TEMPORARY TABLE'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'TEMPORARY INDEX'   WHEN 'S' THEN 'TEMPORARY SEQUENCE'   WHEN 'v' THEN 'TEMPORARY VIEW'   ELSE NULL   END  END  WHEN false THEN CASE c.relkind  WHEN 'r' THEN 'TABLE'  WHEN 'i' THEN 'INDEX'  WHEN 'S' THEN 'SEQUENCE'  WHEN 'v' THEN 'VIEW'  WHEN 'c' THEN 'TYPE'  WHEN 'f' THEN 'FOREIGN TABLE'  WHEN 'm' THEN 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'  ELSE NULL  END  ELSE NULL  END  AS TABLE_TYPE, d.description AS REMARKS  FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n, pg_catalog.pg_class c  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d ON (c.oid = d.objoid AND d.objsubid = 0)  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class dc ON (d.classoid=dc.oid AND dc.relname='pg_class')  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace dn ON (dn.oid=dc.relnamespace AND dn.nspname='pg_catalog')  WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid  AND c.relname LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT' AND (false  OR ( c.relkind = 'r' AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema' ) )  ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE,TABLE_SCHEM,TABLE_NAME 
2017-05-16 09:11:00 CST ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 17221405 at character 20
2017-05-16 09:11:00 CST QUERY:  create temp table  temp_region_partition_info_status(nodeID int, data jsonb) on commit drop
2017-05-16 09:11:00 CST CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_statistic_node_status() line 47 at SQL statement
2017-05-16 09:11:00 CST STATEMENT:  begin;
select fn_statistic_node_status();
commit;
2017-05-16 09:11:00 CST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2017-05-16 09:11:00 CST STATEMENT:  RESET ALL
```

Comment: you must share your transaction with someone else. what is the port number in connection string?..

Comment: the connection user is "postgres", and the port number is 5432.

Comment: strange. `RESET ALL` smells like session/transaction sharing (otherwise why would you want to reset what you set previously. and dropped temp table before commit feels like as well. But you connect to default port... hard to diagnose remotely